# Sidebar height 100% with changing size of div in browser

Tags: height

I got a problem with my website.
On the left I have a sidebar, and next to it I have the container.
At the moment I have found this javascript function:

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#sidebar").height( $(document).height() ); 

});

This script makes sure that my sidebar is 100%. Also if I resize the screen, the sidebar automatically changes height.

The problem is that I have a dashboard in my container with moving divs, who can change size and are stackable underneath each other. (example: http://demo.webdeveloperplus.com/drag-drop-panels/)

If I stack these divs underneath each other, the sidebar does not change height automatically. How can I make sure that the sidebar is also changing height when I stack these divs in the container? Do I need to loop the script?

Hope someone can help me with this.

(ps. I do not have a footer in my website so the sidebar has to keep on the height of the document. (background))

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is a two part answer.  Part one is that you will need to get the height of the viewport for the browser. Part two is that you will need to re-do this function whenever the window resizes. after some testing (in IE 9, Chrome and FF) I've found this to work well:

```
function getClientHeight() {
    var retval = 0;

    if (typeof (window.innerHeight) == 'number') {
        retval = window.innerHeight;
    } else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight) {
        retval = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    } else if (document.body && document.body.clientHeight) {
        retval = document.body.clientHeight;
    }

    return retval;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).resize(function (event) {
        $("#sidebar").height(getClientHeight());
    });

    $("#sidebar").height(getClientHeight());
});
```

Comment: It still does not work. I pasted this code inside the <head>, but the #sidebar div still did not stretch the height after putting those dragable boxes underneath each other inside the container.

It has the height of the full window of the browser, but if the container div gets higher, I get a scroll and see that the #sidebar just stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

I Fixed the problem now. I used another way to set the height of the sidebar always 100%.

For people who want to know how I fixed this:

I gave the #sidebar style: position: fixed; and putted the divs inside the sidebar outside of the div and made a new div #sidebarcontent. Then gave the #sidebarcontent style position: absolute; and placed them on the right place. I tested this for cross browser and it worked even on IE6.